# What do epoch, sequence number, offset, owner, token mean in azure event hubs?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

What do the epoch, sequence number, token, which is stored through the consumer group, mean?

The following forms are stored in azure Blob storage :

```
{  
   "Offset":"8251440",
   "SequenceNumber":10576,
   "PartitionId":"11",
   "Owner":"host-93e93907-df5f-4643-a784-5931e8fb787f",
   "Token":"24f1c215-688f-462f-b78f-142943ab123a",
   "Epoch":2437
}
```

I want to know what these mean

Comment: Please provide more information, this question is not clear.

Comment: @MorShemesh
If you use event hubs through consumer group, the state of each consumer group is stored in the azure storage blob. 

When you open this file, I don't know offset, token, sequence number, mean?

Comment: Even knowing event hub, I'm not sure what you mean, please provide some way to reproduce the problem with a step by step instruction and post an example of the file you are talking about.

Comment: @MorShemesh 
The following forms are stored in azure Blob storage :
{"Offset":"8251440","SequenceNumber":10576,"PartitionId":"11","Owner":"host-93e93907-df5f-4643-a784-5931e8fb787f","Token":"24f1c215-688f-462f-b78f-142943ab123a","Epoch":2437}

I want to know what these mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its times like these that you need to realize there is a world of documentation, you seldom have to guess with Microsoft

[Lease.Epoch Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.lease.epoch?view=azure-dotnet)

> Gets or sets the epoch year of the lease, which is a value you can use
>   to determine the most recent owner of a partition between competing
>   nodes.

[Lease.Offset Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.lease.offset?view=azure-dotnet)

> Gets or sets the current value for the offset in the stream.

[Lease.Owner Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.lease.owner?view=azure-dotnet)

> Gets or sets the host owner for the partition.

[Lease.PartitionId Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.lease.partitionid?view=azure-dotnet)

> Gets the ID of the partition to which this lease belongs.

[Lease.SequenceNumber Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.lease.sequencenumber?view=azure-dotnet)

> Gets or sets the last checkpointed sequence number in the stream.

[Lease.Token Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.lease.token?view=azure-dotnet)

> Gets or sets the lease token that manages concurrency between hosts.
>   You can use this token to guarantee single access to any resource
>   needed by the IEventProcessor object.

Comment: I tried to find only in the Event Hub technical document. I think it was a big mistake. Thank you for the realization.